# Inserting Oracle Solaris 11.2 Repository on VirtualBox Oracle Solaris 11 (64 bit)

Tags: virtualbox, solaris

I downloaded Oracle Solaris 11.2 Repository from Oracle.com and i can't figure out how to uncompress it and insert it on VirtualBox.. Please let me know what steps to take.. Thank you.. My e mail is zfinest1@hotmail.com just incase..

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/local-repository-2245081.html

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

It would have been simpler to download the repository from inside the Solaris virtual machine.

Anyway, with the files in your host machine file system, you can use the shared folder facility to make the file available to the guest, or use whatever file sharing protocol your host support.

After, run the install-repo.ksh script which unzips and installs the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda confused a little on your answer.. sounds good but executing might be a little difficult for me... Are you saying that i can download those solaris files with virtualbox instead of using the regular safari browser to download it? If so they how would i download the files with virtualbox from oracle.com   Thanks!